# I have a piece of code that attempts to makes a box move, it does not work. The language is HTML5 and the code is below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot get this to make the square move, I do not get errors, and I have no clue why. I believe the problem originates from the way the keyboard input is processed or the method it is taken in with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>    

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
</div>

<script>
var pos = 0;
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}

function myEventHandler(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 37) {
        pos = pos - 1
    }
    if(keyCode = 39) {
        pos = pos + 1
    }
}
</script>    
</body>
</html>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `myEventHandler()` function is not called by the code shown.

Comment: 1) Your HTML is invalid. 2) Your event handler is not bound to any element.

Comment: It still not working. Just so you know I'm using Notepad ++, I'll try another editor.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `onkeydown` event listener and you haven't called function to update position of element and really don't need `setInterval` function to do that.

```js
var pos = 100;
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } 
    else {
     
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
  }
}
function myEventHandler(e){

    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 37){
        pos = pos - 1;
        myMove();
    }
    if(keyCode = 39){
        pos = pos + 1;
        myMove();
        }
}
document.onkeydown = myEventHandler;
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you call your routines to initialise the page.  So your script should be:

```
var pos = 0;
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } 



    else {
      elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
    }
  }
}
function myEventHandler(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 37){
        pos = pos - 1
    }
    if(keyCode = 39){
        pos = pos + 1}
}

// added these initialisation calls
myMove();
document.onkeyup = myEventHandler;
```